# Send json message using routes on laravel

Tags: php, json, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-routing

currently I'm trying to test one on my Controllers, that needs a json file as input. The Controller is waiting for the json message using

```
$input = Input::all();
```

My goal is to write a unit test that sends a json file to the controller via routes using for example the `$this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $files, $server, $content)` method from laravel.

I assume I have to enter the json message as a plain string in a value named `$content` like:

```
 $this->content('Json Message String');
```

As `$method` I'm using 'Post' and the `$uri` is the route to my `ImporterController`.

The problem is that the array `$input` on the controller side is always empty, so is there any need of declaring the message being a Json?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out myself. Don't know if anyone is interested in this, but the only thing I had to do in order to send the json message was this:

```
    $json = 'json message';
    $this->params = json_decode($json,true);

    $this->call($this->method, $this->uri,$this->params);
```

So the message had to be declared as json with `json_decode` and stored as a parameter, not as content.

Comment: Okey Good for you. And any others with problem. And you should accept your answer.